# How does Windows News & Interests still work if Location services are turned off?

Tags: windows-10, geolocation, location-services

In the latest Windows update, I have the News & Interests widget on my taskbar that shows me accurate weather info for my current location.

I have Location turned off in my Windows settings, and no apps have permission to access Windows location information. I even checked my location history on my Windows privacy dashboard, and it says there's no location data for me. I also do not have a "default location" set under Windows location settings.

Does anyone know how News & Interests is still accessing my location, and if it's possible to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Check this Microsoft post about this issue:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-desktop-apps-and-privacy-8b3b13bc-d8ff-5460-8423-7d5d5c1f6665

Answer (score 1):

From your IP address, it's possible to find out your
approximate location with an error measured in kilometers,
by identifying the concentrator node of the ISP that handles
your address.

With WiFi this is even worse, because by triangulating from
known wireless networks around you (if enough exist),
your location can be found with a precision of few meters.

There is no simple way to avoid that method.

The only way to confuse such applications is to use a VPN server that
will make it look as if you are located elsewhere in the world.
However, this will cause such applications to act strangely
and make weird decisions about your defaults.